# $m+n$ divides $a_m+a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $m+n$ divides $a_m+a_n$ for all $m<n$. Is it necessary that $n$ divides $a_n$ for all $n$?

Examples of such a sequence is $a_n=kn$ for some positive integer $k$. From $m+n$ dividing $a_m+a_n$ we see that if we fix $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, then $a_n$ is fixed modulo $n+1,n+2,\dots,2n-1$.

Comment: Might I ask, purely out of curiosity, where the question comes from?

Comment: First attempt. For all $n \ge 2$, we have that $$n+2n \mbox{ divides }a_n+a_{2n}$$ $$n+3n \mbox{ divides }a_n+a_{3n}$$ $$2n+3n \mbox{ divides }a_{2n}+a_{3n}$$ hence $n$ divides all these numbers. In particular $n$ divides $$(a_n+a_{2n})+(a_n+a_{3n}) - (a_{2n}+a_{3n}) = 2a_n$$ so $n$ divides $a_n$ whenever $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Crostul you can do the same with $(n,3n,5n)$ to make it work for even $n$ as well. You can post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the hints in the comments:

$$4n\mid a_n+a_{3n}, 6n\mid a_n+a_{5n}, 8n\mid a_{3n}+a_{5n}$$

So $2n\mid (a_n+a_{3n})+(a_n+a_{5n})-(a_{3n}+a_{5n})=2a_n$, hence $n\mid a_n$.